# How can I change the render settings so that the wierd particles on my render look better?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Here you can see my render in Cycles
I want to render this image, but the Cycles engine can't handle the smoke simulation. I would like the render to be way more precise and realistic.

[image: Here you can see my render in Cycles]

[image: My Settings]
[image: My Settings]
[image: My Settings]

I don't know how to adjust the settings so that the end result looks better. Here's the rendered image where you can see this noise looking particles. I want to avoid them so the image looks more professional.